# The custom UITableViewCell can not set the selected background color

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a subclass of UITableViewCell. It adds a few extra elements to the base view (via xib) ,
but It can not take effect.
[image]

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
```

The above two kinds of Settings are unable to take effect.

> cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
>   cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

Two other background style can take effect. I am very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an iOS mistake. There's no more blue selection style since iOS 7. The only selection styles provided are UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone and UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray.

From [UITabieViewCell Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewCellSelectionStyle):

> UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue
>
> The cell has a default background color when selected.
>
> In iOS 7, the selection color is no longer blue. Use UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault instead.
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

If you want, you can set your own custom selection background by setting the `selectedBackgroundView` property of UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

If you have noticed, even in the non custom uitableviewcell, if you set the selection colour as blue or grey , it shows the same colour effect. I guess it is the mistake present in IOS and it is not your fault. I have not tried creating a custom rgb colour for tableview cell. You can try doing that